# convert dynamically the rows to columns with out specifying fields

Tags: mysql

How can I convert dynamically a key-value table using Case without specifying row names?
For example I have this table named `key_value`:

```
id     key     value
1     name     john
2     fname    akbar
3     jobs     Software enginer
.    .    .
.    .    .
.    .    .
.    .    .
.    .    .
n    n    n
```

I want to convert all these rows dynamically to columns without specifying key name like:

```
name   fname   jobs............................n
john    akbar   sofware engineer...........n
```

I have used:

```
Max(Case WHEN key='name' THEN value END) AS name
```

In this query I know my key.
What if I don't know my fields and I don't know how many fields I have?

I want to convert all of this dynamically without specifying my fields.

Comment: By 'convert', do you mean you want to display row values as column headers?

Comment: yes mr Ruben key as header and value as its attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was also my question way back
[SQL Query fields as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667699/sql-query-fields-as-columns)
I modified it to answer yours and I hope it helps just like it did to me!

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(a.xvalue = ''',
      xvalue,
      ''', a.xvalue, NULL)) AS ',
      xkey
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM key_value;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM key_value a
                   LEFT JOIN key_value AS b
                    ON a.id=b.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0adbb/1)

Comment: thanx for replaying ! this is exactly what i want,you saved my life,god bless you bro,again thank you