# MySQL Advance Pivoting

Tags: mysql

Table Name: **tblaccesslog**

```
recordid VARCHAR(50) | datelog DATE | timelog TIME  
1001                 | 2013-12-01   | 08:00:00  
1001                 | 2013-12-01   | 17:00:00  
1002                 | 2013-12-02   | 08:00:00  
1002                 | 2013-12-03   | 08:00:00  
1003                 | 2013-12-01   | 08:00:00  
1003                 | 2013-12-01   | 11:00:00  
1003                 | 2013-12-01   | 17:00:00
```

Table name: **tblemplname**

```
recordid VARCHAR(50) | empname VARCHAR(50)   
1001                 | John  
1002                 | William  
1003                 | Sarah
```

What I would like as a result should look like this:

```
empname | 2013-12-01  | 2013-12-02  | 2013-12-03  
John    | 08:00-17:00 | 00:00-00:00 | 00:00-00:00  
William | 00:00-00:00 | 08:00-00:00 | 08:00-00:00  
Sarah   | 08:00-17:00 | 00:00-00:00 | 00:00-00:00
```

The value **08:00-17:00** is the employees FIRST IN-LAST OUT within the day.
If the employee has only one record within the day, just leave the LAST OUT at 00:00, e.g. **08:00-00:00**, **17:00-00:00**
I tried modifying an answer from my previous question also regarding mysql pivoting
[SQL Query fields as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667699/sql-query-fields-as-columns)
but I cant make it to display the required result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to create the result table in non-piviot mode? make it show `empname | 2013-12-01 | 08:00-17:00 | 00:00-00:00 | 08:00-17:00` ?

Comment: Well, I am currently fixated on the Pivoting right now so I didn't try using non-pivot mode.

Comment: Unless you must, I would suggest to do it non-pivot, and then have simple code to pivot it. The only reason I would see to have pivot at the MySQL level is that if some sort of `sorting`, `grouping`, etc is needed