# Placing all the grades of student1

Tags: mysql

I have a table `subject` which has columns `subject code`, `user_id` and `grade`. Also I have a table for students.

Student table:

```
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
| 17000   | elle |
```

Subject table:

```
| subjcode | user_id | grade |
+----------+---------+-------+
| os1      | 17000   | 90    |
| micro    | 17000   | 90    |
```

What is the right query so that the output will look like this?

```
| user_id | os1 | micro1 |
+---------+-----+--------+
| 17000   | 90  | 90     |
```

Comment: `SELECT stu.user_id, sub.os1, sub.micro FROM Student stu JOIN Subject sub ON stu.user_id = sub.User_Id` should get you close

Comment: Its called dynamic pivot table, I had the same question before and was provided an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667699/sql-query-fields-as-columns

Comment: A 'subject' table would never look like that. That table is something else, 'student_subject', perhaps. Anyway l, to answer your question, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1):

This requires you to combine results from multiple line in one line, which is not easily handled by a SQL query. Plus you cannot get a variable number of fields as a results (what if there are 5 subject matters). This is best handled at the display level with a proper language.

Of course a stored procedure will do it but that's a whole other subject :-)

Comment: so to make this output i need to create another table for the subjects? 
Thank You

Comment: @dat3450 I would argue that's it's precisely what the OP should be doing

Answer (score 0):

Based from my own question before [SQL Query fields as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667699/sql-query-fields-as-columns), your code would look like something like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when subjcode = ''',
      subjcode,
      ''' then grade end) AS ',
      subjcode
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM subject_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM student_table s
                   LEFT JOIN subject_table AS g 
                    ON s.user_id = g.user_id
                   GROUP BY s.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```